# How to undo one elfeed search key binding

Tags: elfeed

The elfeed package binds b to something like this

```
;; https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed/blob/master/elfeed-search.el
(defvar elfeed-search-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (prog1 map
      (suppress-keymap map)
      (define-key map "q" 'elfeed-search-quit-window)
      (define-key map "g" 'elfeed-search-update--force)
      (define-key map "G" 'elfeed-search-fetch)
      (define-key map (kbd "RET") 'elfeed-search-show-entry)
      (define-key map "s" 'elfeed-search-live-filter)
      (define-key map "S" 'elfeed-search-set-filter)
      (define-key map "b" 'elfeed-search-browse-url)
      (define-key map "y" 'elfeed-search-yank)
      (define-key map "u" 'elfeed-search-tag-all-unread)
      (define-key map "r" 'elfeed-search-untag-all-unread)
      (define-key map "n" 'next-line)
      (define-key map "p" 'previous-line)
      (define-key map "+" 'elfeed-search-tag-all)
      (define-key map "-" 'elfeed-search-untag-all)))
  "Keymap for elfeed-search-mode.")
```

In my prelude personal.el, I want to "free up" the b key.
Because I want the letter b to be available for a custom use.

How can I tell emacs to not respect the b binding of elfeed?

Answer (score 2):

```el
(with-eval-after-load "elfeed-search"
  (define-key elfeed-search-mode-map "b" nil))
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13966287